Need to replace special character "/" with another string
My file has:
cat /tmp/f
eno1/tg3
eno2/tg3
eno3/tg3
eno4/tg3

I need to use sed to replace / with = or : 
eno1 = tg3
eno2 = tg3
eno3 = tg3
eno4 = tg3

I tried:
ls -l /sys/class/net/*/device/driver/module |cut -d/ -f5,13 |sed 's/\/\ = /'
But I getting this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated 's' command
And I don't want to use perl etc.

Most posts (and the man page) show the separator as / by default, but in fact whatever character follows the s is the delimiter for that command. So just use s+/+ = + - no need for backslashes.

Never parse ls output if you can avoid it. Always prefer either looping over a shell filename glob, or over the output of find (and if you need details about file metadata, you can use stat). ls is not and has never been a tool for scripting, it’s for interactive usage only.

The question shows a file as input, then a call to ls and sed. Please consider keeping the same example of input data in the whole question.

Perl answer would be perl -pe 's^/^ = ^;' (single replacement per line) or perl -pe 's^/^ = ^g;' for a global replacement. Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) answer would be  raku -pe 's^\/^ = ^;' (single replacement per line) or raku -pe 's:g^\/^ = ^;' (global).

sed is complaining because
sed 's/\/\ = /'

is lacking the separator between the pattern and the replacement - per your expected output I suppose that you just mistakenly typed \ for /, and that you actually meant to type:
sed 's/\// = /'

In general, it's helpful to change sed's separator when dealing with forward slashes, to avoid confusion and to make scripts more readable (the separator is determined by the character immediately following s). E.g.:
sed 's@/@ = @'

However, parsing ls is never a good solution; furthermore, personally, in this case I wouldn't even bother trying to be fancy with a pipe, and I'd just go for a loop¹:
for l1 in /sys/class/net/*; do
    l2="${l1}"/device/driver/module
    [ -L "${l2}" ] || continue

    mpath=$(readlink "${l2}")
    printf '%s = %s\n' "${l1##*/}" "${mpath##*/}"
done


[ -L "${l2}" ] || continue: skips interfaces that don't have a loaded module

Sample output from the above on my machine:
enp114s0 = igc
wlo1 = iwlwifi


¹ Historically, realpath was not widely supported. I haven't worked on enough different systems to assert that this isn't true any more today (I suspect it isn't), so I used readlink here; however if you have realpath available, use that instead.

With any awk:
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS=" = "}{$1=$1} 1' /tmp/f
eno1 = tg3
eno2 = tg3
eno3 = tg3
eno4 = tg3


Instead of walking files in /sys by yourself, you could also query the device information using udevadm (from systemd version 255 or newer for udevadmin info --json and --subsystem-match) for instance:
$ udevadm info --export-db --subsystem-match=net --json=short |
   jq -r '"\(.INTERFACE) = \(.ID_NET_DRIVER)"'
wlp2s0 = iwlwifi
enp3s0 = r8169
lo = null

(assumes all attributes and properties are valid UTF-8 encoded text).

Using awk:
As suggested by @EdMorton, regex /\// can be changed to "/" by changing regex delimiter for better readability.
$ awk 'sub("/", " = ")1'
$ awk 'sub(/\57/, " = ")1'


Using cut:
$ cut -d/ --output-delimiter=' = ' -f 1- file

Because our task is to select two fields and change the delimiter, the following command specifying --delimiter=DELIM and --output-delimiter=STRING may be used:
| cut -d/ --output-delimiter=' = ' -f5,13 

instead of
| cut -d/ -f5,13 | sed 's:/: = :'


With zsh:
$ for f (/sys/class/net/*/device/driver/module(N)) print -r -- ${f:h5:t} = ${f:P:t}
enp3s0 = r8169
wlp2s0 = iwlwifi

Where:

(N): nullglob: expands to nothing if there's no matching file
:h5 modifier: 5-component head (dirname) so on /sys/class/net/enp3s0/device/driver/module gives /sys/class/net/enp3s0
:t: tail (basename)
:P: realpath (expands all symlinks and gives the canonical absolute path).


Please check below practical execution of the requirement:


please do not post image as text, just copy/paste (and comment) your code.
